# How to compute this matrix adequately

Tags: algorithm, matlab, random, matrix, numerical

When I attend a algorithm course,the Prof give us an interesting question about matrix computing.
Given a n*n maxtrix A and n*1 column vector b,we need to compute the corresponding x which satisfy:
                                         Ax=b
Using matlab language,A and b are defined as the following:

```
A=[];
for j=1:n-1
    aj=[];
    aj=[aj;repmat(1,j-1,1)];
    aj=[aj;1];
    aj=[aj;repmat(-1,n-j,1)];
    A=[A,aj];
end
A=[A,repmat(1,n,1)];
b=rand(n,1)*2;
```

we just get the value of x by input:

```
x=A\b;
```

then we check the result by:

```
res=A*x-b;
```

we find many elements' absolute value of res is greater than 1.

But,the Prof tell us that:just adding a randomlized item like the following

```
A1=(A1+rand(n,n)*0.0001)
x1=A1\b;
res1=A*x1-b;        # there ,this is A not A1
```

And we will find that res1's elements all smaller than 1e-4

But,the condition number of A and A1 are almost the same.

I guess this is a accumulated numerical error.But I can't explain this phenomenon mathematically and adequately.
Math geek or CSers know?Thank you.

Comment: I tried for `n=6,10,..` and `max(res)` didn't exceed `0.2`.

Comment: I test it for n = 50, 70, 100,then I get the amazing result

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the matrix A.
There are so many linear equation solvers out there that we can't tell you why in this particular case you would get that effect.
Take a look at this: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html
As you can see under 'Algorithms', there are a total of 7 different solvers for a normal input matrix.
All of them will have certain properties which can affect the numerical error more or less.

Comment: Thank you, may be some algorithms will produce absolutely amazing result. What a pity,I can't know the inner computing procedure.= =